# Php session is not working in firefox

Tags: php, session

Session on page 1:

```
<?php
    session_start('seguimento');
    $_SESSION['seguimento'] = 'lojas';
?>
```

Session on page 2:

```
<?php
    session_start('seguimento');

    if($_SESSION['seguimento']!=='lojas'){
        echo 'some html code'
    }
    else{
        echo 'another html code'
    }
?>
```

I tried to use this to show 'some html code' when the session is `LOJA` and show  'another html' when it's empty. The session works on IE, chrome, opera and safari, but not on firefox.

Anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Remember the semicolons after the `echo` statements.

Comment: Anybody explained this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server's date setting.  Check your computer's date setting.  If your server date and time settings are off, PHP could be setting the session cookie in the past, thus deleting the session cookie. Firefox is more sensitive to this.  IE is not.  This has happened to me several times in the past.  Is this part of some sort of Content Management System?

Comment: The date and time is ok on my web server, the strange thing is this problem only happens in firefox, in all others the session works just fine

Comment: Do you have a live URL we can see to test this out?

Comment: what was the solution then? as you have accepted this answer?